# Python call variable name of string an int

Tags: python, variables, global

I need to acces the attribute class through a loop of names. I wonder how can i make it easy.

```
def dofun():
   class Dict:
       pass

   fun = Dict()
   setattr(fun, X1, 10)
   setattr(fun, X2, 20)
   setattr(fun, X3, 30)
   return fun

def main():
   fun = dofun()
   for i in range(1, 3):
      print(fun.X + i)
      print(globals()['fun.X' + str(i)])
```

None of the prints works..
Thanks!

Comment: Can you format the code properly?

Comment: `getattr(fun, f'X{i}')`…!?

Comment: @AMC Code is properly formatted.

Comment: Can you expand on what your program is meant to do? This is bizarre.

Comment: Note that unless you have defined a variable `X1` somewhere, that `setattr` will fail…

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Why not use a regular ``dict`` instead of using an subclass of ``object`` and working with dynamic attributes? Check out [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)